# Problem while trying to create python generator

Tags: python, generator

I am trying to learn how to use generators, so I wrote this one, but it just prints the same value all the time. Why?

I want it to generate values from 999 down to 100.

```
>>> def gen_a():
        a=999
        while a>99:
            yield a
            a-=1


>>> gen_a().next()
999
>>> gen_a().next()
999
>>> gen_a().next()
999
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you are generating the generator over and over.

Try:

```
f = gen_a()
f.next()
f.next()
```

Answer (score 6):

You're creating a new generator each time.  Try this instead:

```
>>> g = gen_a()
>>> g.next()
999
>>> g.next()
998
>>> g.next()
997
```

Comment: Yeah, we answered at the same time, except I went and ran it and pasted the output, costing me a minute. ;_;